# How to replace "," with tab

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Array list but when I outprint it it goes something like

```
[dddasdsadsadsa , dsa das das dsa ,  dasd asd sad ]
```

I'm trying to get rid of the `[` `]` and the , and put the tab insted but the `\t` don't work...

```
String formatedString = resultList.toString()
                            .replace(",","\t")  //remove the commas THIS IS THE LINE     WHERE DONT WORK
                            .replace("[", "")   //remove the right bracket
                            .replace("]", ""); //remove the left bracket

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,formatedString);
```

Comment: perhaps you should use `.replaceAll(",","\\t")`

Comment: Actually - you don't need to escape anything.  It should just work.  Are you sure you have commas in your string?

Comment: @RafaEl `replace()` replaces all copies too, just not using regex,so the best advice is to *not* use `replaceAll()` because regex is not required.

Comment: What doesn't work? Your code should work OK.

Comment: Didnt work... [ ] where removed insted of \\t it gets \t ...

Comment: @Bohemian I think so. btw, just noticed you've got the diamond symbol.  I voted you last time :D

Answer (score 1):

I think creating so many temporary String(s) is more expensive then simply "stringifying" your `List` by hand - that is code such as this,

```
public static <T> String stringify(java.util.List<T> al) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  if (al != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
      if (i != 0) {
        sb.append('\t');
      }
      sb.append(al.get(i));
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

does not require creating intermediate copies, it also does not transform the separator (or the open and close tokens).